# Android: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0, no answers on the site

Tags: java, android

I have searched for the answer on this website, but I can't find. I can't run my app because of the error below. Please help!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MeusLivrosListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prepararBotoes();
        listarLivros();
        prepararCampoBusca();
    }

    private void listarLivros() {
        MeusLivrosDBManganer dbManganer = new MeusLivrosDBManganer(getApplicationContext());
        List<Livro> livros = dbManganer.recuperarListaLivros();

        adapter = new MeusLivrosListAdapter(livros, this);

        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaDeLivros);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void prepararBotoes() {
        Button btnAdicionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_adicionar);
        btnAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdicionarActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepararCampoBusca() {
        EditText txtPesquisar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_pesquisar);
        if (txtPesquisar != null) {
            txtPesquisar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (count < before) {
                        // Reseta a lista
                        adapter.resetData();
                    }
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MeusLivrosDBManganer .java**

```
public class MeusLivrosDBManganer {

    private MeusLivrosDBHelper dbHelper;

    public MeusLivrosDBManganer(Context ctx) {
        dbHelper = new MeusLivrosDBHelper(ctx);
    }

    public Cursor recuperarLivros() {

        String[] campos = {
                MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_ID,
                MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO,
                MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_AUTOR,
                MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_EDITORA
        };
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.TABLE_NAME, campos, null, null, null, null, null);

        db.close();
        return c;
    }

    public List<Livro> recuperarListaLivros() {
        List<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor c = this.recuperarLivros();

        do {
            Livro l = new Livro();
            l.id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_ID));
            l.titulo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO));
            l.autor = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_AUTOR));
            l.editora = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_EDITORA));
            livros.add(l);
        }while (c.moveToNext());

        return livros;
    }

    public boolean inserirLivro(Livro livro) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_AUTOR, livro.autor);
        values.put(MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_EDITORA, livro.editora);
        values.put(MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO, livro.titulo);

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        long resultado = db.insert(MeusLivrosDBContract.Livro.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        db.close();

        return resultado != -1;
    }


}
```

adapter **MeusLivrosListAdapter**

```
public class MeusLivrosListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Livro> implements Filterable {

    private List<Livro> listaDeLivros;
    private Context context;
    private Filter livroFilter;
    private List<Livro> listaDeLivrosOriginal;

    public MeusLivrosListAdapter(List<Livro> planetList, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.layout_lista_livros, planetList);
        this.listaDeLivros = planetList;
        this.context = ctx;
        this.listaDeLivrosOriginal = planetList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listaDeLivros.size();
    }

    public Livro getItem(int position) {
        return listaDeLivros.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return listaDeLivros.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        LivrosHolder holder = new LivrosHolder();

        //Verifica se a view está nula
        if (convertView == null) {
            // recupera a view
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_lista_livros, null);
            //recupera os campos da view
            TextView idLivro = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idLivro);
            TextView tituloLivro = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tituloLivro);


            holder.livroIDView = idLivro;
            holder.livroTituloView = tituloLivro;

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (LivrosHolder) v.getTag();

         Livro l = listaDeLivros.get(position);
         holder.livroIDView.setText(String.valueOf(l.id));
         holder.livroTituloView.setText(String.valueOf(l.titulo));


        return v;
    }

    public void resetData() {
        listaDeLivros = listaDeLivrosOriginal;
    }


    /* *********************************
     * Usamos o padrão holder
     * Isto deixa a view mais rápida, pois evita ficar procurando o componente
     * **********************************/

    private static class LivrosHolder {
        public TextView livroIDView;
        public TextView livroTituloView;
    }



    /*
     * Criamos nosso filtro
     */

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (livroFilter == null)
            livroFilter = new LivroFilter();

        return livroFilter;
    }



private class LivroFilter extends Filter {



    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // Implementamos a lógica do filtro
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            //sem filtros, retorna a lista toda
            results.values = listaDeLivrosOriginal;
            results.count = listaDeLivrosOriginal.size();
        }
        else {
            // Executamos a opração de filtragem
            List<Livro> nLivroList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Livro p : listaDeLivros) {
                if (p.titulo.toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                    nLivroList.add(p);
            }

            results.values = nLivroList;
            results.count = nLivroList.size();

        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {

        // informamos ao adapter sobre a nova lista filtrada
        if (results.count == 0)
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else {
            listaDeLivros = (List<Livro>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    }
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.juliosampaio.meuslivros/com.juliosampaio.meuslivros.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                               Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
>                                                                                  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
>                                                                                  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
>                                                                                  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
>                                                                                  at com.juliosampaio.meuslivros.MeusLivrosDBManganer.recuperarListaLivros(MeusLivrosDBManganer.java:47)
>                                                                                  at com.juliosampaio.meuslivros.MainActivity.listarLivros(MainActivity.java:33)
>                                                                                  at com.juliosampaio.meuslivros.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)

Comment: It seems that the cursor you are getting from the `recuperarLivros()` method is empty. I also noticed that the data bese helper class does not get called with a database name! Are you sure that you have the matching content in the databese? Its always good practive to use `if(cursor.moveToFirtst())` statement when working with cursors.

Comment: Goto line 47 of your MeusLivrosDBManager.java make sure your static values for column names are correctly match with the database.

Answer (score 1):

The main possible reason is your cursor doesn't have data inside, you can't be sure that until you check the condition, and you should always be aware that `do` loop executes once without checking any conditions, Then only after executing single time, It checks the condition.

So I suggest do not use `do while` loop while looping the cursor to prevent crashing,

It's always better doing like this

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ...
}
```

**OR**

However if you want to use `do while` loop, Then you should check `if (cursor.moveToFirst())` before looping like

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        ...                 
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```